# How to get a comma-separated single address from a SQL Server database where some elements might be NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So this is a pretty standard requirement; I have a table holding address information and I want to pull out a single, "formatted" address with all the fields concatenated with comma separators.

The problem is that some fields can be NULL and so I end up with trailing commas.  For example, one address might be "10 The Strand, London" with no country on the end but the next one might be "5 Fleet Street, London, England".  If I pick out each address element and assume it is always present then I would present these two addresses as:

"5 Fleet Street, , , London,"

"10 The Strand, , , London, England"

Getting rid of the extra commas from the middle is simple, just a test for NULL.

I know how to fix the trailing comma problem in two passes, either using a CTE or a subquery, but can this be done in a single pass through the data?

Here is an example using a CTE:

```
DECLARE @Address TABLE (
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    Line1 VARCHAR(255),
    Line2 VARCHAR(255),
    Line3 VARCHAR(255),
    City VARCHAR(255),
    Country VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @Address VALUES ('Complete', 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Oxford', 'England');
INSERT INTO @Address VALUES ('Incomplete', '22 Accacia', NULL, NULL, 'York', 'England');
INSERT INTO @Address VALUES ('Missing End', '10 Bond Street', NULL, NULL, 'London', NULL);
WITH Addresses AS
(
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Name + ', ' END + 
    CASE WHEN Line1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Line1 + ', ' END + 
    CASE WHEN Line2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Line2 + ', ' END + 
    CASE WHEN Line3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Line3 + ', ' END + 
    CASE WHEN City IS NULL THEN '' ELSE City + ', ' END + 
    CASE WHEN Country IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Country + ', ' END AS [Address]
FROM
    @Address)
SELECT LEFT([Address], LEN([Address]) - 1) AS [Address Clean] FROM Addresses;
```

Which gives me:

```
Complete, Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Oxford, England
Incomplete, 22 Accacia, York, England
Missing End, 10 Bond Street, London
```

Why do I want this?  Partly because I can't think of a way to do this but "feel" there should be a way to get what I want and partly because this query is running over a linked server to a SQL 2000 box and so I can't use CTEs (although I could easily rewrite the query using a sub query instead).

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Can you repeat the question? It looks to me like you've already answered the question in your title.

Comment: *So this is a pretty standard requirement* for rendering in the presentation layer yes. For processing in the storage, not so much. Do it on the client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), for example:

```
WITH Addresses AS
(
SELECT
  coalesce(Name, '') + 
  coalesce(', ' + Line1, '') + 
  coalesce(', ' + Line2, '') + 
  coalesce(', ' + Line3, '') + 
  coalesce(', ' + City, '') + 
  coalesce(', ' + Country, '') AS [Address]
FROM
    @Address)
SELECT Address FROM Addresses
```

This will return the first parameter that is not null, so for example if `Line1` is null, then '' will be returned (otherwise `,Line1`).

Note that for this to work, [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) must be set to `ON`.

Results against the test data:

```
Complete, Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Oxford, England
Incomplete, 22 Accacia, York, England
Missing End, 10 Bond Street, London
```

Comment: How does this helps with the trailing comma?

Comment: Ok, still, how do you pretend to get rid of the last trailing comma?, you know, the one that is making op doing the `LEFT(colum,LEN(column)-1)`?

Comment: Ok, my bad: see my second edit, the comma should precede the field.

Comment: Nice note about  CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL. It's often forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

I did a couple of things here.  First I used `ISNULL` to determine if the value was `NULL` and if so return a `''` (empty string).  I added the `', '` as a delimiter to the value before testing to see if it is `NULL` or not.  This way if the column is null then the column+delimiter is also `NULL` and the `ISNULL` test still returns a `''`.  I put the delimiter before the column value to make it easier to remove the extra delimiter.  Had the extra delimiter been at the end of the string then I would have had to use a `LEN` function or something similar to calculate where the extra delimiter was.  This way it is always at the beginning of the string and by using the `STUFF` function I could replace the first 2 characters with a `''` effectively removing them.

```
DECLARE @Address TABLE (
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    Line1 VARCHAR(255),
    Line2 VARCHAR(255),
    Line3 VARCHAR(255),
    City VARCHAR(255),
    Country VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @Address VALUES ('Complete', 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Oxford', 'England');
INSERT INTO @Address VALUES ('Incomplete', '22 Accacia', NULL, NULL, 'York', 'England');
INSERT INTO @Address VALUES ('Missing End', '10 Bond Street', NULL, NULL, 'London', NULL);

SELECT STUFF(
        ISNULL(', '+Name,'') + ISNULL(', '+Line1,'') + ISNULL(', '+Line2,'') + 
        ISNULL(', '+Line3,'') + ISNULL(', '+City,'') + ISNULL(', '+Country,'')
    ,1,2,'')
FROM @Address
```

Comment: Excellent, I forgot about STUFF.  I actually ended up using your method as it copes with a missing Name slightly better than the COALESCE method does.

Comment: In this particular case `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` are pretty much equivalent.  `ISNULL` is just my personal preference for single column tests.  @Geoff's version is just missing the `STUFF` command (`SUBSTRING`, `LEFT` or `RIGHT` would also have worked depending on how you set it up.)  I on the other hand missed the mention of `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`.